# Retrieve file name from path with Invantive SQL

Tags: sql, invantive-sql, accountview

For a conversion of AccountView XML input files to XML Auditfile Afrekensystemen (Cash Registers) I need to generate an output file name without a path. The query is:

```
select f.file_path file_path_src
,      replace(f.file_path, '.xml', '.xaa') file_path_tgt
,      xmltransform(cnt.file_contents, xsl.file_contents) xaa_contents
from   files('${rootpath}\input', '*.xml')@os f
join   read_file_text(f.file_path)@os cnt
on     1=1
join   read_file_text('${scriptpath}\convert-account-view-to-xaa.xsl')@os xsl
on     1=1

local export documents in xaa_contents to "${rootpath}\output" filename column file_path_tgt
```

However, the `local export documents` statement requires the file name to consist solely of the base name and the extension. When you include directory structure in it, it will generate funny file paths like `<root path>\c_\folder\...`.

How do I extract the name of the file without directory path and without extension from `f.file_path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following query I now get a file name without directory:

```
select f.file_path file_path_src
,      regexp_replace(f.file_path, '^(.*[\\/]|)(.*).xml$', '$2.xaa') file_path_tgt
,      xmltransform(cnt.file_contents, xsl.file_contents) xaa_contents
from   files('${rootpath}\input', '*.xml')@os f
join   read_file_text(f.file_path)@os cnt
on     1=1
join   read_file_text('${scriptpath}\convert-account-view-to-xaa.xsl')@os xsl
on     1=1
```

The part:

```
regexp_replace(f.file_path, '^(.*[\\/]|)(.*).xml$', '$2.xaa')
```

takes a file path such as `c:\folder\...\accountview.xml`, splits it into three parts:

- From start till the last found forward or backward slash is put in $1.
- After the slash till the occurrence of a trailing `.xml` is put in $2.
- The trailing `.xml` is another part, but not referencable in the replace string.

The `$2.xaa` gives me on the file path as output: `accountview.xaa`.